# Filter button using for loop crashing

Tags: angular, typescript

I have it a buy it now only filter button that filters listings that allow that option. Right now with the for loop in the code below, the app crashes when button is clicked. If I remove the for loop, it doesn't crash. I don't really understand the crashing because I'm looping correctly. Atleast I think I am. Does anyone see an issue with my code? beforeCurrentFilter is supposed to reset the filter prior that button click. I have 3 filters total so if more than one is selected, it should revert I think.

```
filteredPosts: any[] = [];
posts: any[] = [];
beforeCurrentFilter: any[] = [];



      buyItNowFilter() {

        if (this.buyItNowStatus) {
          this.buyItNowStatus = false;
          console.log("ITS TRUE");

          return;
        }
        if (!this.buyItNowStatus) {
          console.log("its false");
          this.beforeCurrentFilter = this.filteredPosts;

          this.buyItNowStatus = true;

          for (let i = 0; i < this.posts.length; i++) {
            if (this.posts[i].auctionType !== "Not Available") {
              console.log("LISTING HERE");
              console.log(this.posts[i]);
              this.filteredPosts.push(this.posts[i]);
            }
          }
          this.posts = this.filteredPosts;
        }
      }
```

Comment: is there an error of some kind in your console?

Comment: Not that I can see. When I click the button, I have to kill the firefox or chrome process and reopen so I don't really get a log output

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the this.filteredPosts.push causing the freeze. Is it a declaration issue?

Comment: Why are you starting at 1? The arrays are zero based right?

Comment: Yea lol. I was just playing around with it. I forgot to change it back

Comment: I don't do angular, so this is an educated guess, but I think `this.posts = this.filteredPosts` does not copy the array but rather points `posts` at `filteredPosts`, so the next time you press, they are the same array and so posts gets longer on every push, resulting in an infinite loop (as long as at least one thing is pushed),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor your code to look like this and it should fix your issue, if you use the `Array.filter` method you can eliminate the use of the for loop

```
buyItNowFilter() {
  if (this.buyItNowStatus) {
    this.buyItNowStatus = false;
    console.log('it\'s true');
    return;
  } else {
    console.log('it\'s false');
    this.beforeCurrentFilter = this.filteredPosts;
    this.buyItNowStatus = true;

    this.filteredPosts = this.posts.filter(x => x.auctionType !== 'Not Available');
    this.posts = this.filteredPosts;
  }
}
```